# How Can I perform Addition on Big Decimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have Column in Database which has value stored in this format "0.0000000000"
I need to retrieve this value from database and perform Add operation to this value like "0.000000000000 + 0.0000000001"
How can I print the whole value as output in console?
And Is is possible to convert the output into String format?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is the database connection working? Are you mapping the value already to a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)? There are methods for all binary operations in `BigDecimal`. This class also has a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to avoid `1E-10` expression
you can do that as

```
BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal("0.0000000000").add(new BigDecimal("0.0000000001"));
System.out.println(bigD.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using add() method you can perform the addition of two Bigdecimal.BigDecimal has overloaded constructor you can pass the double, float, string etc.

```
BigDecimal a  = new BigDecimal(0.000000000000);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.0000000000001); 

BigDecimal sum = a.add(b);
```